# Camel jms request/reply threading model

Tags: apache-camel, camel-jms

I am using camel jms in a synchronous way using request-reply pattern.The camel route exposes a cxf endpoint and it places the message in to the jms queue another component process it and sends the response in replyto queue.

A new thread is getting created while receiving the reply from replyto queue?Iam facing issues with using log4j MDC with in the camel route.The values store in MDC are no more available?

Is it the behaviour of camel jms request/reply pattern?

Below is the JMS endpoint:

```
<to id="QueueEndpoint" pattern="InOut" uri="hornetq:queue:{{esb.api.requestqueue}}?replyTo=queue:{{esb.api.responsequeue}}&amp;useMessageIDAsCorrelationID=true&amp;replyToType=Exclusive&amp;requestTimeout={{esb.api.queue.requesttimeout}}"/>
```

Comment: What version of Camel do you use. And what keys/values do you store on MDC - eg some custom or the OOTB from Camel.

Comment: Iam using camel 2.17.0.redhat-630310. I am storing custom metadata values like sourcesystem,sourcetransactionid etc.

Comment: See this SO question and answer about custom MDC fields
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29045419/apache-camel-mdc-add-field-from-body/29045968#29045968