# MDC.get(key) doesn't work in apache camel route

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel

I'm trying to put value in MDC in apache camel route, but when I go to the next pipeline I'm unable to fetch the value in MDC

Can someone please help me on this?

MDCTest.java

```
@RunWith(CamelSpringBootRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = App.class)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@Slf4j
public class MDCTest {
  @Autowired private ProducerTemplate producerTemplate;

  @Autowired private CamelContext camelContext;

  private String someEndPoint = "kafa:myEndPoint";

  @EndpointInject(uri = "mock:" + "Something")
  private MockEndpoint destinationEndPoint;

  @Test
  public void testTheInsertionIntoMDC() throws Exception {
      camelContext.setUseMDCLogging(true);
      camelContext
         .getRouteDefinition("route-id")
         .adviceWith(
              camelContext,
              new RouteBuilder() {
                @Override
                public void configure() throws Exception {
                interceptSendToEndpoint("direct:a")
                .skipSendToOriginalEndpoint()
                .process(
                    m -> {
                      MDC.put("key","value");
                    })
                // I get a null value in the next statement of log
                .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "Trying to fetch the value: " + MDC.get("key")) 
                .to(destinationEndpoint);
          }
        });

      producerTemplate.sendBody(someEndPoint, someBody);
      destinationEndpoint.expectedMessageCount(1);
      destinationEndpoint.assertIsSatisfied();
   }
}
```

I have created a normal test case where I just put key and value in MDC and assert it and it works fine. But does not work when I try to do it in Camel.

Comment: Your test doesn't show everything unfortunately (`someEndPoint` isn't defined, no assertions on the MDC values, your missing the `@AdviceWith` annotation, ...), hence it may depict only half the truth. Are you using `seda` endpoints in your test? Do you spawn new threads somewhere? MDC works on a thread-local basis meaning that the information is only available within the same thread the `MDC.put(..., ...)` occurred. Any other thread wont have this information available by default unless you manually copy it over to the new thread.

Comment: I have added someEndPoint. If I assert it fails saying MDC.get("key") is null, so it throws NullPointerException. Where do I need to put @AdvideWith annotation? I'm not using SEDA endpoints. I'm not spawning any other thread as well. Anyway, the thread that gets spawn is local to the route, so ideally I should get the output of MDC in log.

Comment: You could follow the approach [recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29045419/apache-camel-mdc-add-field-from-body) by @ClausIbsen. A working example of this approach can be seen in [my tech demo](https://github.com/RovoMe/camel-rest-dsl-with-spring-security/tree/master/src/main/java/at/rovo/awsxray/config/mdc). Note that you should configure the header values that should be used for MDC like [this](https://github.com/RovoMe/camel-rest-dsl-with-spring-security/blob/master/src/main/java/at/rovo/awsxray/config/SpringConfig.java#L89-L91)

Comment: I have actually used your tech demo approach. It all works fine. I get the MDC in my logging. But when I try to test it doesn't work. I'm not able to test the MDC key part.